# What kind of transformer was used in this led driver?

Tags: led, switch-mode-power-supply, led-driver

I'm trying to examine the parts of the led bulb that I disassembled. I'm having a hard time distinguishing what kind of transformer is mounted on the circuit.

I'm planning to build a driver for my power leds so maybe I can hack the circuitry that is used on this kind of bulb. I read that SMPS is used for these drivers but I'm confuse on the transformer that was used. Here is the photo btw...

Thank you guys!

Comment: Learn to take useful pictures.

Comment: Impossible to tell without schematic. It might be a flyback transformer.

Comment: A rectangular one, in gray, black and blue.

Comment: @venny thanks! I understand...so maybe I'll just try to search for schematic on powerleds..

Comment: @Ecnerwal Oh really, you are cool bro! cool dude! Thanks for dropping by

Comment: That photo is near useless, the others are just pointing that out. However, to answer your question, SMPS's generally use transformers designed for the purpose. They are designed to operate at a specific high frequency and have a designed amount of reluctance. Other than that, we'd need much more information and a better photo.

Comment: Hey, man, you're like, so welcome - that was about as complete and correct an answer as I can give from the supplied picture without making unwarranted assumptions. While it might be a SMPS, even that is not clear from a picture where a postage stamp would cover all the relevant parts. Try again, closer and from other angles. If it is a SMPS in a commercial product, it's almost always going to be an utterly custom item anyway...

Answer (score 2):

It's a switched-mode power supply transformer.

That power supply is unlikely to have any isolation between the mains and the LEDs because it is designed to be integrated with the LEDs into a sealed enclosure - the bulb. Mains voltages may be present on the LEDs and this will present a serious / fatal shock hazard. Purchase a proper power supply for your application.

Olin is right. 80% of the picture area is irrelevant. You should crop it.

Comment: It could quite easily be a linear supply.

Comment: @transistor Hi, thank you for your answer....   I'm just quite disappointed how the others responded given that they have such "reputation".   Anyway Thanks again!

Comment: When joining a forum it's always a good idea to get a feel for the standard of posting and the type of answers before posting. Your question was poor in regard to the photo. The item in question takes up about 1% of the area of the photo so we can't see any detail and we have no idea what the back of it looks like (which would give us a clue as to the number of pins). Ask some more questions but show how much work you've done yourself and be specific about what information you want. Take my warnings about mains voltages seriously.